# Is there a way to delay page refresh once the submit button has been pressed?

Tags: jquery

I have a success message that is displayed once the submit button is pressed, however, it disappears straight away when the page refreshes.  With this in mind what I would like to do is delay the page refreshing for 5 seconds or so.  I have tried using

```
setTimeout(function() {location.reload();}, 5000);
```

within my code but just can't seem to get it to work

Any help would be great.

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {

        // error variable set to blank
        var error ="";
        // if subject value is equal to an empty string
        if ($("#email").val() == "")  {
            // error variable to add comment advising that data is missing
            error += "No data in email field - please complete.<br>";
        }

        if ($("#subject").val() == "")  {
            error += "No data in subject field - please complete.<br>";
        }

        if ($("#content").val() == "")  {
            error += "No data in content field - please complete.";
        }

        // if error variable is not equal to blank as error variable += html value
        if (error != "") {
            $("#errorDiv").html('<div><p><strong>Whoops! There were error(s) in the form:</p></strong><br>' + error +'</div>');
        }

        if (error != "") {
            $("#errorDiv").css("display", "block");
            return false;
        } else {
            // return true and allow submission of the submit button as no error msg as all fields have been entered correctly
            $("#successDiv").css("display", "block").html('<div><p><strong>Thank you for your enquiry, we will get back to you shortly!:</p></strong><br></div>');

            setTimeout(function() {
            location.reload();
            }, 5000);

            return true;
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
//declare outside your submit  
function startTimer() {
     location.reload();
}

//change your timeout func to
setTimeout(startTimer, 5000);
```

Edit with ajax :

```
$('yourFormButton').on('click', function () {

    // error variable set to blank

    var error ="";
    // if subject value is equal to an empty string
    if ($("#email").val() == "")  {
        // error variable to add comment advising that data is missing
        error += "No data in email field - please complete.<br>";
    }

    if ($("#subject").val() == "")  {
        error += "No data in subject field - please complete.<br>";
    }

    if ($("#content").val() == "")  {
        error += "No data in content field - please complete.";
    }

    // if error variable is not equal to blank as error variable += html value
    if (error != "") {
        $("#errorDiv").html('<div><p><strong>Whoops! There were error(s) in the form:</p></strong><br>' + error +'</div>');
        $("#errorDiv").css("display", "block");
    } else {
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET", // or Post
        url: yourUrl,
        data:  $("form").serialize(),
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data) {
            setTimeout(startTimer, 5000);
        },
        error : function(data){
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This won't submit the form data. He better use ajax.

Comment: True but we need an url though .. Editing

Comment: The form probably has the url, but generally his validation and posting is wrong, should be done better way.

Comment: The validation works fine, however, you mention the posting is wrong - could you elaborate more?  Knowledge is power so always good to get feedback

Comment: Just managed to try it out now but no joy unfortunately and with further thought even with a delay on refreshing of the page I will still encounter a problem as the form in which I am using is a pop out window so if the user clicks on the close button of the form the page will still refresh after the pop out window has been closed(not good).  Back to the drawing board I think.  Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
     //your code....
     setTimeout(function() {
         window.location.reload();
      }, 5000);
   });
```